# How to delete operator== (and !=) for floating point variables

Tags: c++

Because of the unstability of floating points getting compared, I want to have at least a warning when using the comparison operator.

Example:

```
float a,b;
a == b; // Here the warning shall be thrown
```

How can I realize that?

I thought of overloading like:

```
inline bool operator==(const float& a, const float& b)
{
    #warning "Usage of equal on floating point variables not allowed."
    return false;
}
```

I didn't found it clear stated, but it seems that overriding of this operator is forbidden as MSVC throws C2803 and gcc throws "must have an argument of class or enumerated type" (also described in [Global overloading of == and != for floating-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795959/global-overloading-of-and-for-floating-points)). Even if it would be possible, the compiler would throw an error when he comes across the #error statement even if not used.

Comment: Why are you trying to overload an operator for a built in type?

Comment: What do you mean by *Because of the undefined behaviour of floating points getting compared*?  There is no undefined behavior in float comparisons.

Comment: Comparing floats is not UB. It's not even inherently wrong. It only has a high potential for not working out the way you wanted.

Comment: Do you mean that since it's hard to compare two floating point values with each other because of rounding, it should be explicitly forbidden? Then *how* would you instead compare them? There are accepted and well-working ways to compare floating point values using an epsilon, do you want to forbid that too?

Comment: We have another comparison method does take eps into account. To force the usage of those who state clearly what is going to happen I want the compiler to throw an error.

Comment: @harold yes true. HOwever, it is very unlikely that the same thing will happen across different enviroments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading comparison for double to allow for numerical error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263482/overloading-comparison-for-double-to-allow-for-numerical-error)

Comment: Careful of some of the [pitfalls of comparing floats using an epsilon value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/77735/1277769)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with custom operator overload wont work because C++ standard forbids custom operator overloads if all their arguments have builtin types.

**If you're using GCC (or clang/MinGW) you can use `-Wfloat-equal` to enable the warning about those comparsions.** It's the closest thing you can get.

Even if it would be possible to completely disable them, it would be a bad idea. Sometimes they are useful and completely safe. Especially if there are no computations.

Consider following code:

```
float f = 0;

if (a >= -1 && a <= 1)
    f = std::asin(a);

// ...

if (f != 0)
    std::cout << "asin = " << f << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "Out of range.\n";
```

It's completely safe even though it uses `==` with `float`.

Comment: Good example. I changed my question to reflect that. It whould still throw at least warning imo, to make the developer aware that he might do something unstable.

Comment: @Davidius I found a flag for GCC to enable this warning. I guess something similar exists for MSVC too.

Comment: oh nice, that's exactly what I was looking for. Hope I can find that in MSVC too.